# Links are shown, but you can't click on them?

Tags: html

On my site, pages where I have added links to the footer (like http://msdhosting.tk/signup/) but when I move over them and try to click them, they don't appear to be links and they don't go anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `#footer` has `z-index:-9999;` which positions it behind the `<body>`.
When you try to click links in the footer, you're actually clicking the `<body>` and not the links under it.

I suggest removing the `z-index` definition from `#footer`.

If there is a reason you need the footer behind something else, try moving the other element up with a positive `z-index` rather than moving `#footer` back with a negative one.

Comment: @MStratford - To help debug in the future, if you have any tools to inspect elements on your page (like Firebug), inspecting any of the footer elements takes you to the body tag instead of the footer div which tells you the footer is not "on top".

Comment: I noticed that @ChadCook! Didn't realise!

Answer (score 1):

You gave your footer a z-index of -9999. That appears to be placing your footer behind other elements on the page.